# storing arabic text in mysql using pdo in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on arabic site and for that I want to store the arabic input in database. I've set the character set to `utf8mb4_general_ci`. When I'm printing the data before the insert query, then it is showing me correct arabic value. But when I am inserting it into db it is storing as `Ø§ÙØ±ÙØ§Ø¶â`. I am using PDO in PHP and I've also set the character set to utf 8 in connection string.

```
$this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->settings["user"],   
$this->settings["password"], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

But I am not able to store arabic character in my table.

Answer (score 1):

When setting client charset, one have to make it **match the actual data encoding.**

So, if your input data is in `utf-8`, everything should work, but in this case why would you set database charset to `utf8mb4`, not `utf8`?

If your input data encoding is different from `utf-8`, then you have to set names to match this actual encoding.

Also, setting charset in `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` is but a superstition. Although in most cases it plausible, better set it via DSN - it works for all the currently supported PHP versions. Note that encoding names are slightly different from commonly used.

Regarding strange characters you're observing - it's most likely no more than *measurement error*. The tool you are using to browse the database, have to both support that encoding and **set up to display it properly.**

All the above is based on the assumption that

> I'd set the character set to utf8mb4_general_ci.

statement is about setting the table charset.

Comment: using ut8_general_ci also getting the same problem

Comment: i got the solution. I'd set charset with this code

mysql:dbname='.$this->settings["dbname"].';host='.$this->settings["host"].'';
        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->settings["user"], $this->settings["password"], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

and in bind function there was utf8_encode function which again converting the string to utf8. So i'd removed the utf8_encode function and its working fine now.